Autoencoder for semi-supervised anomaly detection - a choice of loss function, scaler and activation function
I am trying to build an autoencoder for semi-supervised anomaly detection on an intrusion detection dataset (CICIDS2017). The dataset has data with very wide range (like between 0 and 1+08).
I am struggling with choosing a combination of scaler, final layer activation function, and loss function.
What did I try:

MinMaxScaler (range 0 to 1) + Sigmoid activation function for output + Binary Cross Entropy Loss. The result: A model does not seem to be learning, loss is very small and stuck quickly, the final ROC-AUC is very low. I suspect that after scaling, most of the data lands in a very narrow space, making it impossible for the model to learn properly.
MinMaxScaler (range 0 to 1) + Sigmoid activation function + MSE - similarly, the model does not learn.
StandardScaler + LeakyReLU activation function + MSE error - the model is learning for a little bit reducing loss by around 25%, but then it gets stuck.
RobustScaler + LeakyReLU activation function  + MSE error - huge loss value, no real learning.

I feel like I am missing something obvious, so I would greatly appreciate your suggestions on how to make the learning process work.
Model's architecture

    encoder = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(78, 64),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Linear(64, 32),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Linear(32, 16),
        nn.ReLU()
    )

    decoder = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(16, 32),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Linear(32, 64),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Linear(64, 78),
        nn.LeakyReLU()
    )

Example features
                             count          mean           std           min         25%           50%           75%           max
Destination Port             2572640.0  8.522897e+03  1.886345e+04  0.000000e+00   53.000000     80.000000  4.430000e+02  6.553500e+04
Flow Duration                2572640.0  1.625736e+07  3.495376e+07 -1.300000e+01  200.000000  48854.000000  5.225583e+06  1.200000e+08
Total Fwd Packets            2572640.0  1.011604e+01  7.863759e+02  1.000000e+00    2.000000      2.000000  5.000000e+00  2.197590e+05

